# How to write 0 as first character in input type text field

Tags: javascript

I have an input field and I am putting value in it dynamically so I am getting 01 value to put in the text box

```
$('#final_result').val(open+close);
```

I have an input field which id is final_result and I am getting 0 in open and 1 in close as a number. I try to convert it into string like

```
$('#final_result').val(toString(open)+toString(close));
```

but still getting 1 in input I want 01 in input field.

Comment: You want to print "01" if you enter 1 in the input?

Comment: whatever i am getting in open and close i want to combine that and print it in input but if i get 0 in open then i am getting only the close value

Comment: Try using :  $('#final_result').val('+open+''+close+');

Comment: still same result

Comment: Should be `open.toString() + close.toString()`

Comment: Yes this works thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#final_result').val(open+""+close);
```